# Editing last gdb command in AIX

Tags: gdb, aix

I would like something similar to bash command line, where we can rescue the last command, and navigate left and right among characters to edit the command before entering it.

Are there ways to edit the last command entered in gdb in AIX systems ? Or at least there are ways to come back some characters to correct it, rather than, delete all them with backspace ?

(I have noticed that dbg line-editing works fine in Linux)

Comment: How did you compile gdb? It has `readline` included, also it is able to use pre-installed readline.

Comment: I didn't. It was only installed by another team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a copy of gdb built without libreadline support. Either go without it or re-build gdb from source w/ libreadline support.

Answer (score 1):

GDB uses the same line-editing library as bash -- GNU readline.  The editing you do in bash should work fine in GDB.  It does for me.

Comment: Sure, I tested it in Linux and the line-editing works as bash, but not for AIX. I'll edit the question to have AIX system as the environment. Tnx.